# question on complex/real numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

A matrix has two eigenvalues: $\lambda = \dfrac{z \pm \sqrt{z^2-4w}}{2}$. I want this matrix to be stable (that is, $|\lambda| < 1$).

Inorder to achieve this, I thought about doing two cases: the case when eigenvalues is complex and the other when they are real.

Do I really need to do both? Can I just do the case of complex numbers, and since $\mathbb{R}$ is just a subset of $\mathbb{C}$, then we are finished?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you dont reallz separate the cases for $\lambda$ being complex and real.

You separate the cases based on the sign of $z^2 - 4w$:

- If $z^2-4w \geq 0$, then $\lambda_{1,2} = \frac{z\pm\sqrt{z^2-4w}}{2}$
- If $z^2 - 4w < 0$, then $\lambda_{1,2} = \frac{z\pm i\sqrt{4w-z^2}}{2}$

So no, I don't think you can join the two cases.

Comment: Note that if the eigenvalues are real, they can be whatever you want (as long as it's not too big, of course), while in the complex case they _have_ to be complex conjugates of one another.